# How do you add extra property using join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

If I have an entity:

```
class Post
{
    [ Key ]
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    ...

    public bool LikedByUser; // Append this property
}

public class PostLike
{
    public int PostLikeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can do a join on a call to the database and just append this last property (mentioned in the code) as an extra... for example, this code is stupid (and probably doesn't work):

```
this.context.Posts
    .Join( 
        this.context.PostLikes,
        p => p.PostID,
        pl => pl.Post.PostID,
        // This is the bit that can't be right!
        ( p, pl ) => new Post()
        {
            PostID = p.PostID,
            Title = p.Title,
            Body = p.Body,
            Comment = p.Comment
            Project = p.Project,
            LikedByUser = pl.Count > 0 ? true : false
        }
    );
```

I would like something like this:

```
this.context.Posts
    .Join( 
        this.context.PostLikes,
        p => p.PostID,
        pl => pl.Post.PostID,
        ( p, pl ) => {
            p.LikedByUser = pl.Count > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Sidebar: the `pl.Count > 0 ? true : false` can be shortened to just `pl.Count > 0`.

Comment: 1. Is LikedByUser a property that not exists in class Post?
2. IS class Post partial?

Comment: 1. LikeByUser is a property that exists on the class Post, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

So - one way you could do this, is via a sub-query:

```
var posts = this.context.Posts
    .Select(p =>
    new Post()
    {
        PostID = p.PostID,
        Title = p.Title,
        Body = p.Body,
        Comment = p.Comment
        Project = p.Project,
        LikedByUser = this.context.PostLikes.Any(pl => pl.PostId = p.PostID)
    });
```

If that property isn't part of the existing class - you could project into an anonymous type, for use:

```
var posts = this.context.Posts
    .Select(p =>
    new {
        Post = p,
        LikedByUser = this.context.PostLikes.Any(pl => pl.PostId = p.PostID)
    });
```

Comment: I think that property is not part of the class

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to create a mapping object for it?